# Empty local database after filling it

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, local-database

I'm using local database to store my data in Windows Phone 8 application. At first I have data stored in JSON object which is converted to my classes objects and then collection of these objects I try to store in local database. I was checking in debug mode and data is in those objects, but when I check database, it's empty.

This is how I move data from collection to database:

```
// Data context for the local database
private TablesDataContext tablesDB;

// Define the query to gather all of items.
var customersTablesInDB = from CustomerItem todo in tablesDB.CustomersTable
                                select todo;

// Execute the query and place the results into a collection.
CustomersTable = new ObservableCollection<CustomerItem>(customersTablesInDB);

foreach (Customer customer in customersList) 
{
    // Create a new item
    CustomerItem newCustomer = new CustomerItem 
    { 
        Id = customer.id,
        Number = customer.number.Value,
        Name = customer.name,
        Email = customer.email
    };

    // Add item to the observable collection.
    CustomersTable.Add(newCustomer);

    // Add item to the local database.
    tablesDB.CustomersTable.InsertOnSubmit(newCustomer);   
}
```

Here is my class for `DataContext`:

```
public class TablesDataContext : DataContext
{
    // Specify the connection string as a static, used in main page and app.xaml.
    public static string DBConnectionString = "Data Source=isostore:/Customers.sdf";

    // Pass the connection string to the base class.
    public TablesDataContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    { }

    // Specify a single table for the items.
    public Table<CustomerItem> CustomersTable;
}
```

And here is my `CustomerItem` class:

```
[Table]
public class CustomerItem : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    // Define ID: private field, public property and database column.
    private int _id;

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = false, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_id != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Id");
                _id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
    }

    // Define item name: private field, public property and database column.
    private int? _number;

    [Column]
    public int? Number
    {
        get
        {
            return _number;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_number != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Number");
                _number = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Number");
            }
        }
    }

    // Define completion value: private field, public property and database column.
    private String _name;

    [Column]
    public String Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Name");
                name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    // Define completion value: private field, public property and database column.
    private String _email;

    [Column]
    public String Email
    {
        get
        {
            return _email;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_email != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Email");
                _email = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Email");
            }
        }
    }


    // Version column aids update performance.
    [Column(IsVersion = true)]
    private Binary _version;

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Used to notify the page that a data context property changed
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanging Members

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    // Used to notify the data context that a data context property is about to change
    private void NotifyPropertyChanging(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanging != null)
        {
            PropertyChanging(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a "tablesDB.SubmitChanges();" ?

Comment: You never run the `Insert` query. All `InsertOnSubmit` does is "Adds an entity in a pending insert state to this Table<TEntity>."  This means the changes are just pending.  When your application closes the pending changes are likely just discarded.

Comment: @robertftw Yes, I added that line, and everything works fine. Thank you:). Write it as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a "tablesDB.SubmitChanges()" after your foreach-loop.